# Does sanitizing data eliminate the possibility of SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

By sanitizing data before it is used, am I still at risk of SQL injection? If so, what standard should I be using to eliminate the possibility of SQL injection? I was told the code below was subject to SQL injection. However, I sanitize the data before it's used in the query so I'm not sure if the risk is still there.

```
VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"].$_SESSION["setCount"]."', '".$_SESSION["username"]."')
```

I've read several questions and researched SQL injection but I'm still not sure if I'm checking all of the boxes. It seems like the most common are data sanitization, program structure and restricting which variables the user has access to.

Comment: Theoretically, yes.  But the right way is to use parameters.  And parameters have other advantages as well, such as caching query plans.

Comment: @GordonLinoff By using parameters, do other precautions need to be taken? It seems like parameters remove SQL injection but are there other potential risks that arise?

Comment: . . Your code might be easier to write, debug, and run faster.  I suppose there are situations where any of those could be considered a risk ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements:

**Example:**

```
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (usernameCount,username) VALUES (?,?)");
$insert->bind_param("ss", $usernameCount, $username);

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$usernameCount = $_SESSION['username'] . $_SESSION['setCount'];

$insert->execute();
```

In `bind_param` method the first parameter is the data type of each parameter.

Each `s` corresponds to each parameter `$usernameCount` and `$username`.

Comment: Do prepared statements and bind_param treat the data as field parameters rather than actual SQL code?

Comment: To answer my own question for anyone else who reads this, this method does treat values as field parameters rather than actual SQL code.

Comment: @csell PDO can ship the query and the data independently over the connection if driver-native prepared statements are available and enabled. If PDO is in "emulation" mode then it composes the query with your data, but does so in a safe way, so regardless of what mechanism is used you should be fine.